# Selecting one object and printing it's attributes AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, ngmodel

I am using **angular-auto-complete** for an Airports list.

Basically is a list of objects each with the following attributes: name, city, iata, etc. **I have two identical "dropdowns", one for Arrival airport, one for Departure.**

Inside my controller I can get the attributes of "this" model but I don't know how to store it to be able to output it later.

As it is now the binding is just echoing the text value of the input model, obviously.

Here the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/udkys1eo/8/

From the controller I can do

```
$scope.arrivalAirport = selectedObject.
```

But that doesn't make sense since the event is triggered for both auto-complete fields.

Ideally I want to achieve:

```
thisModel = selectedObject;
{{thisModel.name}}
{{thisModel.city}}
```

But I don't know how, I have googled and tried for hours.

Thanks, I am new in Angular.